# What is the definition of real numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

I only know that the rational and irrational are together called real numbers. Rational numbers can be written in the form $\frac {p}{ q}$ ,where $p \in \mathbb Z$ and $q \in \mathbb Z$.

Are there any additional information which I left? If 'yes' then please tell me the alternative definitions.How to answer it in an interview? Thank you in advance.

Comment: p and q are co prime

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261074/true-definition-of-the-real-numbers

Comment: real numbers are by definition limits of converging (Cauchy) sequences of rationals. think to the decimal expansion

Comment: The real numbers can be constructed by means of Dedekind cuts. If you'd like to learn more about this, you can read about it in any good real analysis textbook.

Comment: @Danny seriously, your advice is to look at the Dedekind cuts ?..

Comment: @user1952009 Why is that bad advice?

Comment: @user1952009: I would say that Dedekind cuts are a more natural definition of $\mathbb R$ than Cauchy sequences, mainly because an irrational number has one and only one Dedekind cut. But it's really just a question of personal preference.

Comment: @TonyK yes you are right, let's learn the Dedekind cuts (a purely theorical object) before the infinite decimal expansion and the series expressions for $\sqrt{2},\ln 2, e,\pi,\ldots$

Comment: @user1952009: Students already know what a decimal expansion is before they have to learn a rigorous definition of $\mathbb R$, so it's just a question of conceptual simplicity. And in my book, a subset of $\mathbb Q$ is a simpler concept than an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rationals. (And whatever your view on the matter, there is no need for sarcasm here.)

Comment: @TonyK the sarcasm is because you can't understand such a theoretical object as the Dedekind cuts before knowing the Cauchy sequences construction of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @user1952009: Yes I can. And did, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to notice first for this is that some sequences of $ \mathbb{Q} $ do not converge to a value in $ \mathbb{Q} $. In fact, for every real number, you can find a sequence of $ \mathbb{Q} $  that converges to that number (for example the different fractional series converging to $ \pi $).
The idea is to create the set of "limits" of sequences of rational numbers.

However, you can't just write $ \displaystyle\mathbb{R} = \{\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}u_n, u\in\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}\} $, since it doesn't mean anything until you've defined $ \mathbb{R} $, because the limit itself isn't defined.

What you need is to create an equivalence relation over the "converging" subset of $ \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N} $ and identify the equivalence classes as elements of $ \mathbb{R} $. But first you'll need Cauchy sequences, which can be used to show that sequences have a converging behaviour but without specifying their limits.

---

We say that a sequence $ u $ is a Cauchy sequence iff $ \forall\varepsilon>0, \exists N, \forall n \ge N, \forall m \ge N, |u_n - u_m |<\varepsilon $
It is easy to show that if $ u $ converges in $ \mathbb{Q} $, then it is a Cauchy sequence.

Let $ A $ denote the subset of $ \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N} $ of Cauchy sequences.
Let $ \sim $ be a relation on $ A $, with $ \displaystyle u \sim v \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}u_n - v_n = 0 $ (we can define this properly because $ 0 \in \mathbb{Q} $ and $ u - v \in \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N} $).

It is then easy to show that $ \sim $ is and equivalence relation :

- Reflexivity : $ \displaystyle\forall u \in A, \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}u_n - u_n = 0 $
- Symmetry : $ \displaystyle \forall (u, v) \in A^2, \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}u_n - v_n = 0 \implies \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}v_n - u_n = 0 $
- Transitivity : if $ u \sim v $ and $ v \sim w $, then we have $ \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}u_n - w_n = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}u_n - v_n + v_n - w_n = 0 $.

Then $ \mathbb{R} = \{[u], u \in A\}$ is the set of equivalence classes of $ \sim $, and every Cauchy sequence of rational numbers defines a real number.

This construction is due to Cantor if I remember correctly. There are some other constructions using Dedekind cuts for example, but this is easy enough to understand (but no so much to use).

Comment: In other words: $\mathbb{R}$ is a *subquotient* of the ring $\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}$. (A ring $R$ is a said to be a *subquotient* of a ring $S$ iff $R$ is a quotient ring of a subring of $S$.)

Comment: That might be _a bit_ hard to grasp for people not familiar with category theory.

Comment: Its just ring theory...