# Once again about Dedekind cuts

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Assume I have a Dedekind cut: $(-\infty,a)\cup(a,+\infty)$. This Dedekind cut defines irrational number $a$. And $(-\infty,a]\cup(a,+\infty)$ defines rational. I have a few questions about this:

1. How to prove that $\Bbb R$ in which every number defined this way is continuous?
2. How to prove that Dedekind cut defines only one number?
3. How to prove that there are no more excluded points on axis?

What if Dedeking cut actualy defines some weird interval like $\{\sqrt{2}-\epsilon\;;\sqrt{2}+\epsilon\}$ that does not contain rational numbers? And in that terms irrational number is not a point on axis, but that kind of weird microcontinuum interval.

Comment: What do you mean, precisely, by $\Bbb R$ being continuous?

Comment: None of these questions are meaningful without defining your terms.  What do you mean by "continuous"?  What do you mean by "number"?  What do you mean by "points on axis"?  Usually, Dedekind cuts are used to _define_ real numbers, such that statements like these are essentially definitions, not theorems.

Comment: Well I mean that every Dedekind cut defines only one point on real axis.

Comment: Dedekind cuts are defined as a pair of subsets of $\mathbb{Q} $ and not as a union of intervals. You need to get your definitions correct by going through any standard reference. An answer here also gives a proper definition which may be helpful for you (although it uses one subset instead of a pair).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't describe a Dedekind cut as $(-\infty,a)\cup(a,+\infty)$, since this needs the irrational number $a$ to be defined, while the whole goal of Dedekind cuts is of course to define the irrational numbers.

---

The way I like to see Dedekind cuts, is as a set $X\subset \Bbb Q$ of rationals, such that:

- $X$ is not empty and $X$ is not all of $\Bbb Q$,
- $X$ is downward closed (i.e.: for any $x\in X$ and any $y<x$ also $y\in X$),
- $X$ has no maximal element (i.e.: for any $x\in X$ there is some $y\in X$ such that $y>x$).

Often Dedekind cuts are described as two sets, the other set being $\Bbb Q\setminus X$, but including this second set is not really necessary.

There are two important cases: either $X$ has a least upper bound (inside $\Bbb Q$), or it does not. For example, the set $\{q\in \Bbb Q\mid q<2\}$ is a Dedekind cut that has least upper bound $2$, while the set $\{q\in\Bbb Q\mid q<0\lor q^2<2\}$ is also a Dedekind cut, but does not have a least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$.

The **real numbers** $\Bbb R$ are *defined* to be the set of all Dedekind cuts on $\Bbb Q$. If $X,Y$ are two real numbers, we say that $X\leq Y$ if $X\subseteq Y$. So the ordering of real numbers comes straight from the inclusion of the Dedekind cuts that define them.

We call a real number $X$ *rational* if $X$ has a least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$, and call it *irrational* if $X$ does not have a least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$. To avoid confusion, I will say "rational number" whenever I mean an element $q\in\Bbb Q$ and I will say "rational real" whenever I mean a Dedekind cut with a least upper bound in $\Bbb Q$.

In practice and intuitively, we often see a real number as some kind of *point* on a line, instead of a set of rational numbers. However, this line, and this point, are *defined* by Dedekind cuts. Hence we cannot *prove* that a real number is a point on a line, since we *define* both the point and the line using Dedekind cuts.

---

Let's look at your three questions:

1. A set cannot be continuous. Continuity is a property of functions between topological spaces, not a property of sets. However, there is such a thing as the property of being a *continuum*, which is probably what you meant. A continuum is any set that is *dense* and *complete*.

   Denseness means that if $x<y$, then there is some $z$ such that $x<z<y$. The real numbers are dense, since $\Bbb Q$ is dense: if $X$ and $Y$ are Dedekind cuts, and $X\subsetneq Y$, then there is some $q\in Y$ with $q\notin X$. Because $Y$ has no maximal element, there is some $r>q$ with $r\in Y$. Then the set $Z=\{p\in \Bbb Q\mid p<r\}$ is a Dedekind cut that is in between $X$ and $Y$. Note that $Z$ is not just any real number, it is a rational real.

   Completeness means that for any set of reals $R\subset \Bbb R$ that has an upper bound, there is a least upper bound of $R$. This follows quite easily from the definition of Dedekind cuts, since we can just take the union of the Dedekind cuts in $R$. This union is a Dedekind cut itself, since $R$ has an upper bound (and thus there is some $Z\in\Bbb R$ such that $X\subsetneq Z$ for all $X\in R$, meaning $Z$ contains some rational number $q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q\notin X$ for any $X\in R$).
2. As said before, we cannot *prove* that a Dedekind cut defines one number, since we define real numbers to be exactly the same as Dedekind cuts. Using the definition, this question asks for proving that every Dedekind cut defines one Dedekind cut.
3. Similarly here, we cannot prove this, since both points and axis are *defined* to be exactly all of the Dedekind cuts. There are no excluded points, is saying that no Dedekind cuts are excluded. But this is obvious by definition, since "the set of all Dedekind cuts" contains "all Dedekind cuts".

Finally your last remark, does there exists some weird interval $[\sqrt 2-\epsilon,\sqrt 2+\epsilon]$ not containing any rational reals? You are defining this interval using two real numbers $X=\sqrt 2-\epsilon$ and $Y=\sqrt 2+\epsilon$.

Since real numbers are Dedekind cuts, suppose that $X\subsetneq Y$. Then, as we saw in the proof of denseness, there exists some rational real $X\leq Z\leq Y$. However, we asked for an interval $[X,Y]$ **not** containing any rational reals. Therefore $X\not\subsetneq Y$, and thus $X\geq Y$.

This shows it is impossible to have an interval containing more than one real that does not contain any rational reals.

Comment: As I understand the statement that bijection between $\Bbb L$ and $\Bbb R$ where $\Bbb L$ is a set of points of the line is an axiom. So we just believe and for us it looks obvious that line defined this way has no gaps. By the way $X = \sqrt 2-\epsilon, Y = \sqrt 2+\epsilon$ are not real numbers. The idea is that all rational and irrational numbers are sets. The length of $(\sqrt 2-\epsilon, \sqrt 2+\epsilon)$ interval is smaller than any number, but not equals zero. If we postulate this axiom the line still has gaps.

Comment: How do you define 'line'? What axioms are you speaking of? We don't 'believe' anything, we define things and then prove statements about what we defined. If you don't define what your concepts mean, you're not doing mathematics. The real line has no intervals of infinitesimal length, I proved that at the bottom of my answer. It follows from how we defined the real line using Dedekind cuts. Of course I can define different 'lines' (e.g. the surreal numbers) in a different way such that your property becomes possible. But it's not for the real line.

Comment: The geometrical line is a primitive notion, like point, function, set, etc. There is no problems with real numbers defined as rationals plus Dedkind cuts of special case (irrationals). If we are talking about real numbers as a set of some elements, i'm fine with that. The problem with geometry. We say that if rational and irrational numbers are interpreted as points on geometrical line there is no gaps. Who said that there is no gaps anymore? Can you guarantee that there is no possible geometrical paradox that states that there is a line segment which length is neither rational nor irrational.

Comment: This discussion really makes no sense unless you start to define precise *which* axioms you're using and *how* you define the reals. 

I can guarantee that there are no gaps of the kind you describe in the real line as defined using Dedekind cuts. If you define the reals using Dedekind cuts, then the real line is *not* a primitive notion, but a defined notion.

If on the other hand you describe the line as a primitive notion that satisfies, for example, Hilbert's axioms, then infinitesimal intervals don't exist because you assume the Archimedean property. In non-Archimedean geometry (...)

Comment: (...) it becomes possible for infinitesimal intervals to exist. So it really really matters what your assumptions are. So, once again, *what axioms are you speaking of*?

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But unfortunately I can't formulate corretly what I mean.

Comment: I think finding a good way to formulate what you mean goes before finding an answer to the questions you have. More often than not, confusion is the product of not understanding the assumptions you're working with. Instead of trying to show the real line has no gaps, try to start with trying to formulate what "real line" means. Not as an intuitive concept, but as a rigorous mathematical object. See this answer for some ideas on how to define the real line: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/261077/176025